# How do you approach being on the fence between research and industry at the end of your PhD?

Tags: career-path, industry

I've got a little less than a year left in my PhD and I intend to search for a job this fall/winter. The question is to where should I direct my efforts -- academia/research or industry? At the very least, I've narrowed it down to either a US national lab postdoc or an industry job. My field is condensed matter physics but I want to get into quantum hardware. I just don't know if I can get an industry job there without some postdoc experience.

**Pros and cons of the national lab postdoc:**

1. Pros

   - Extra time to tailor and adjust my career path
   - Temporary 2 year segment
   - Opportunity to move into a staff scientist position
   - Independent study experience in quantum hardware that would bolster my resume
   - I'd be a shoe-in with my existing collaboration
2. Cons

   - Feeling stuck in a different form of the academia rat race
   - Temporary 2 year segment
   - Lower pay with potentially longer hours
   - Sometimes frustrating work with no end in sight

**Pros and cons of an industry job:**

1. Pros

   - Higher pay, better working hours?
   - More living location choices
   - No need to worry about funding a project
2. Cons

   - Less independence
   - Feels like a bigger job commitment than a postdoc
   - I don't have a good network of people in industry
   - Challenging to find something I'm qualified for while still intellectually stimulating

I'm sure I have incorrect assumptions about some of these. What is a mindful way to approach the next step after a PhD if you're on the fence like I am, and how can I make the right choice?

Comment: Unclear on how different the salary would be - national labs pay much better than university postdocs. Hours will be similar. All have funding considerations.

Answer (score 9):

The decision you ultimately make probably depends not only on the general job characteristics which you have listed, but also the specific characteristics of any job offers you receive. In other words, if the only postdoc offer you receive is in a location you don't like, you may prefer to work in industry.

My advice is to apply for both types of jobs, and then evaluate or compare the actual job offers that you receive. If you only receive postdoc offers, then that may be the default choice. If you have both industry and postdoc offers, you can decide between them based on the specifics of salary, location, and what you would be working on.

Comment: Should I be transparent about vacillating between the two in interviews?

Comment: There's no need to, and it would probably not help you. Every hiring committee assumes that interviewees are interviewing elsewhere. Hiring committees also want to hire someone who will take the job, and stating that you are vacillating is also stating that you're not sure whether you want the job you're interviewing for.

Comment: That's why I thought it might make me a better candidate if I just picked one or the other. Makes sense not to draw attention to it if it turns out I'm applying to both.

Answer (score 1):

Your decision depends on your own values, talent, and temperament. Industry probably does pay higher. The stress can be off the charts when layoffs come and you've settled into a community, so there's that. But you're right about not having to hunt for funding in the same way as you do in academic research. An advantage many people in industry find is that, perhaps unexpectedly, there can be pretty diverse opportunities. You might discover in a few years that you're well-suited to running a group of junior scientists.

Everything changes. Neither academia nor industry are the same as when some of us started all those years ago. It'll be the same for you.

Comment: You make another good point about diverse opportunities. I do enjoy the capability to change up my work and responsibilities from time to time.

Comment: Best of luck! With an environment of diversity comes, potentially, opportunities to discover and develop those sides of yourself you really can’t afford to in your early career.